# Flask-Pydantic disable validation on get request

Tags: flask, pydantic

I have a flask view that accepts a get and post request and I use Pydantic for request body validation using flask-pydantic. It works fine for post requests but on get requests it returns a 415 error with this message -
**{"detail":"Unsupported media type '' in request. 'application/json' is required."}**

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST',))
@validate()
def login(body: UserLoginSchema):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        existing_user = UserListSchema.from_orm(
            db_session.query(UserModel.id, UserModel.email, UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name,
                             UserModel.is_admin, UserModel.is_verified, UserModel.password)
            .filter_by(email=body.email, is_active=True).first()
        )
        if existing_user:
            if check_password_hash(existing_user.password, body.password):
                session.clear()
                session['user'] = str(existing_user.json())
                return redirect(url_for('index'))

        flash('Invalid username or password')
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

I have tried setting the *query* parameter in the function to an empty string or None and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the flask-pydantic package and initialised the pydantic models manually because the validate decorator from flask-pydantic requires the content-type header to be set to **application/json**.

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST',))
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        body = auth_schemas.UserLoginSchema(**request.form)
        existing_user = auth_schemas.UserListSchema.from_orm(
            db_session.query(UserModel.id, UserModel.email, UserModel.first_name, UserModel.last_name,
                             UserModel.is_admin, UserModel.is_verified, UserModel.password)
            .filter_by(email=body.email, is_active=True).first()
        )
        if existing_user:
            if check_password_hash(existing_user.password, body.password):
                session.clear()
                session['user'] = str(existing_user.json())
                return redirect(url_for('index'))

        flash('Invalid username or password')
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

Then I created a **ValidationError** handler to catch validation errors while initializing the pydantic model classs.

```
from pydantic import ValidationError


@app.errorhandler(ValidationError)
    def handle_pydantic_validation_errors(e):
        return jsonify(e.errors())
```